# How to pass file url to helper method in middleman

Tags: ruby, middleman

I'm writing a helper method to convert images to base64 strings when needed. Below is the code

```
  # config.rb
  helpers do
    def base64_url(img_link, file_type: "jpg")
      require "base64"
      if file_type =="jpg"
        "data:image/jpg;base64,#{Base64.encode64(open(img_link).to_a.join)}"
      elsif file_type =="png"
        "data:image/jpg;base64,#{Base64.encode64(open(img_link).to_a.join)}"
      else
        link
      end
    end
  end
```

In page.html.erb

`<%= image_tag base64_url('/images/balcozy-logo.jpg') %>`

Now the problem is when ruby reads `'/images/balcozy-logo.jpg'` it reads the file from system root not from the root of the project.

Error message as follows

```
Errno::ENOENT at /
No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /images/balcozy-logo.jpg
```

How do I get around this and pass proper image url from `project_root/source/images`

Comment: Do you know you have `data:image/jpg` in both branches of your `if`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Middleman `app.root` returns the root directory of the application. There's also `app.root_path`, which does the same but returns a Pathname object, which is slightly more convenient:

```
full_path = app.root_path.join("source", img_link.gsub(/^\//, ''))
```

The `gsub` is necessary if `img_link` starts with a `/`, since it would be interpreted as the root of your filesystem.

I've taken the liberty of making a few more revisions to your method:

```
require "base64"

helpers do
  def base64_url(path, file_type: "jpg")
    return path unless ["jpg", "png"].include?(file_type)

    full_path = app.root_path.join("source", path.gsub(/^\//, ''))

    data_encoded = File.open(full_path, 'r') do |file|
      Base64.urlsafe_encode64(file.read)
    end

    "data:image/#{file_type};base64,#{data_encoded}"
  end
end
```

I've done a few things here:

1. Moved `require "base64"` to the top of the file; it doesn't belong inside a method.
2. Check `file_type` at the very beginning of the method and return early if it's not among the listed types.
3. Instead of `open(filename).to_a.join` (or the more succinct `open(filename).read`), use [`File.open`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/File.html#method-c-open). OpenURI (which supplies the `open` method you were using) is overkill for reading from the local filesystem.
4. Use [`Base64.urlsafe_encode64`](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.0/libdoc/base64/rdoc/Base64.html#method-i-urlsafe_encode64) instead of `encode64`. Probably not necessary but it doesn't hurt.
5. Remove the unnecessary `if`; since we know `file_type` will be either `jpg` or `png` we can use it directly in the data URI.

There may be a more elegant way to get `file_path` or determine the file's MIME type using Middleman's built-in asset system, but a very brief search of the docs didn't turn anything up.

Comment: Thanks a ton for the effort you put into this. I had to change two things to make it work.

The full_path line misses the source directory thus it is not finding the file, So I tried this `full_path = app.root_path + "#{:source}" + path.gsub(/^\//, '')` and it worked.

For some reason `urlsafe_encode64(file.read)` encode didn't work, so just went ahead with `encode64(file.read)` Now its working perfectly fine.

Also tested with png, all fine. Thanks again :)

Comment: Marked as accepted answer, Please update the code for those who come later. I could have done that, but I'd like you to do the honors :)

Comment: `:source` is just a symbol, which is a special kind of string in Ruby, so `"#{:source}"` is equivalent to `:source.to_s`, which is just `"source"`. I've updated my answer to use `app.root_path.join("source", path.gsub(...))` instead of `app.root_path + path.gsub(...)`.

Comment: I used `:source` assuming that it would be same source found in middleman config, I thought if user has different source folder set for the project the snippet would still play along, So I used `:source` instead of hardcoding `source` directory. BTW you are missing a closing bracket in `full_path` line ;)

Comment: Nope, `:source` is a [Symbol](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Symbol.html), not a variable or method. `:foo.to_s` will always return `"foo"` (and `"foo".to_sym` will return `:foo`).